# Image height gets ignored

Tags: flutter

I have the following simple `main.dart` file where I have Gridview with 4 images:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'theme/config.dart';

void main() => runApp(_MyApp());

class _MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: configTheme,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.network(
              'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              height: 100,
            ),
            Image.network(
              'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            Image.network(
              'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            Image.network(
              'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In the first `Image` element I apply `height: 100` but this get ignored (no matter what the value is).

How can I fix that so I can apply any height?

Answer (score 0):

```
Scaffold(
     
      body: new Container(
        child: new GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          controller: new ScrollController(keepScrollOffset: false),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            children: <Widget>[
            Image.network(
              'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              height: 100,
            ),
            Image.network(
              'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            Image.network(
              'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            Image.network(
              'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/06/30/business/30india-tech-1/30india-tech-1-articleLarge.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp&disable=upscale',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```